# how to get route parameters in angular2 RC5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have upgraded my angular2 project to `RC5` using `angular-cli@webpack`.

I have provide routing as below:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'project-manager', component: ProjectManagerComponent },  
    { path: 'designer/:id', component:DesignerComponent } ,
    {path: '',redirectTo: '/project-manager',pathMatch: 'full'} 
];
```

and I am redirecting to designer Component using routerLink as :

```
<a [routerLink]="['/designer', page._id]"><i class="fa fa-eye fa-fw"></i></a>
```

Now It is getting redirected successfully and I am able to see param value in address bar of the browser.

Now I want to know , How can I access this parameter in DesignerComponent in angular2 RC5.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe you need to use the ActivatedRoute from the router to manipulate your parameter.

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

...

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, ...) {
}

// TODO :: Add type
value: any;  // -> wanted parameter (use your object type)

ngOnInit() {
    // get URL parameters
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.value = params.id; // --> Name must match wanted parameter
    });
}
```

Don't forget to import `OnInit` from `@angular/core` if you need it as well.

**N.B :** You can also use `this.route.snapshot.params` to access it synchronously.

---

**EDITED :**

- Cleanup to avoid subscription because the NG2 router manages his subscriptions on his own.
- Avoid using private variables that might be used in the HTML to avoid breaking AOT compilation.
- Cleaned `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` because it's deprecated.
- Avoid using string literal : params['id'] => params.id
- Type your parameter with TypeScript if you have it

Comment: Color me confused.  Why do I need to subscribe to what is a fixed value in the current active url?  It isn't like it is going to change.  I am sort of surprised there is not something like @Input to handle this kind of thing.

Comment: Update : For those interested : there is no need to get the subscription from the observable and unsubscribe in an `OnDestroy` event. The route manages it on his own.
You can actually cut `this.sub`.

Comment: Edited answer to get up to date !

Answer (score 5):

First import `ActivatedRoute` from `@angular/router`.

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
```

access it constructor as below :

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){            
}
```

subscribe to params change inside ngOnInit as below :

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    if (params['id']) {
    }
  });
}
```