# I want to route to external Angular application by passing query parameters to received thos parameters and developed the url from that

Tags: angular

I have one main application and one secondary application.Both application are developed using Angular and their backend is same.I want to make a router from Main application to secondary application with provided some query parameters.

Currently my main applications is running on localhost:4200 and the secondary application is on port localhost:4300,

I want to provide a default url every time,from main application to secondary application.

I have idea of using window.location.href='url' but I need to provide extra query params.

I also try with router.navigate(['']) and router.navigateByUrl([]) but no luck.Looking for good advice,there are many question but no concrete answer to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

you can get router params by injecting ActivatedRoute into your component where you want to redirect. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39163734/how-to-get-route-parameters-in-angular2-rc5) has it. Then construct your url, something like

```
const url = `${protocol}//${host}:4300?queryParam=${queryParam1}`;
```

and then [navigate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign)

```
location.assign(url);
```

You can't use router.navigate, cause each application has its own router instance which navigates in scope of its app. Once you change url via location.assing - new app and its router come to work

Comment: Thanks @Olena Is it possible to fetch the query params in my secondary application?

Comment: use same approach  - get parameters by subscribing to ActivatedRoute params or query params or  getting them from ActivatedRoute snapshot